# jQuery fade hover animation on images breaks links

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code http://jsbin.com/iKOpIYu/5/edit

Users cant click the image until the animation is over.

If you make the animation longer you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animates on the image are doing nothing because you didnt tell it what to animate. I took those out and saw no difference to the fade in and out on the TEST mask.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.boxInner').mouseenter(function(e) {

        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(2000);       
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

Doing this Im able to click the link to google whenever. Even though Im pretty sure I was still able to click it even when they were in

http://jsbin.com/iKOpIYu/7